# counting total number of selected elements in a HTML document , before console.logging it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to build a Jquery plugin that helps me count the total number of times a selected element is present in a HTML document : so i wrote the following Jquery Plugin :

```
(function($){

    $.fn.test = function(options){

        var new_src,
        src_storage = [];


        return this.each(function(){
                get_prop($(this));
                log_it();
        });


        function log_it(){
            console.log(src_storage.length);
        }

        function get_prop(current){
            var temp = current.attr('src');
            src_storage.push(temp);
        }

    }

}(jQuery));
```

now suppose i call the plugin the following way :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').test();
});
```

now the results i get in the console is as follows: (i have 9 images in my HTML doc)

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

now the result i was expecting was :

```
9
```

but i guess the order of execution is such in my plugin that , immediate after      get_prop($(this)); function is called the log_it() function gets called .

so how do i 1st count the total number of elements in the document , before logging them ?

**EDIT :**  The following approach works , not sure how good or clean it is though :

```
this.each(function(){
    get_prop($(this));
});

return this.each(function(){
        log_it();
});
```

Thanks , you're help will really be appreciated .

Tenali .

Comment: Why are you not using $('img').length property of Jquery ? It will also return 9 in your case.

Comment: @SeeTheC i am coding a plugin , not just writing a one time snipet . but i'll try that approach too . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove the log_it function from the return this.each, else it will execute the log_it() function for EACH element.

```
    this.each(function(){
            get_prop($(this));
    });
    return log_it();
```

Comment: Does this approach compromise chanability ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want only length then use only like this:

```
this.each(function(){
    get_prop($(this));
});

return log_it();
```

You are getting all the number because you called that in a loop `each` in your previous codes.

Here is link hows you can start developing plugin, its starting steps. http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/nxskb319/)**

Comment: Does this approach compromise chanability ?

Comment: @TenaliRaman can you tell me in details what you are talking about? I can't understand.